# Ошибка при обновлении Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Вылетает вот такая ошибка при обновлении студии
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда нажимаю повтор, то она скачивает пару мегабайт и снова выдаёт ошибку. Могу нажимать повтор и в конце концов она обновится, но это как по мне не нормально.
Такая же фигня была, когда я её устанавливал, но нажимая повтор, я её всё же установил и подумал, что больше не будет проблем.

Также, когда я хочу установить библиотеку из nuget, то выпадает ошибка, что хост принудительно разорвал соединение.

У меня предположение, что эти две проблемы как-то связаны. Интернет у меня нормас.
Кто знает, что можно предпринять?

Comment: windows10? Перезагрузите  комп (он недавно поймал обновление) и снова попробуйте обновить студию. Недавно похожая проблема была с обновлением.

Comment: @pincher1519 такая проблема наблюдалась ещё месяца 4 назад

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моём случае проблема была в протоколе туннелирования. У меня стоял pptp, я поменял на l2tp и всё начало работать