# Не устанавливаются библиотеки из nuget

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget

При попытке установить библиотеку (например VkNet) выводится следующее

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'VkNet.1.32.0' with respect to project 'VkNet', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'
Gathering dependency information took 6,63 sec
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'VkNet.1.32.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'VkNet.1.32.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'VkNet.1.32.0'
Retrieving package 'HtmlAgilityPack 1.7.0' from 'nuget.org'.
Retrieving package 'JetBrains.Annotations 11.1.0' from 'nuget.org'.
Retrieving package 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10' from 'nuget.org'.
Retrieving package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async 1.0.168' from 'nuget.org'.
Retrieving package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.21' from 'nuget.org'.
Retrieving package 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29' from 'nuget.org'.
Retrieving package 'NetFx.Extensions.DependencyInjection 2.0.1' from 'nuget.org'.
Retrieving package 'NetFx.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.0.1' from 'nuget.org'.
Retrieving package 'NLog 4.5.0' from 'nuget.org'.
Retrieving package 'SimpleInjector 4.0.12' from 'nuget.org'.
Retrieving package 'VkNet 1.32.0' from 'nuget.org'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/htmlagilitypack/1.7.0/htmlagilitypack.1.7.0.nupkg
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.bcl/1.1.10/microsoft.bcl.1.1.10.nupkg
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/jetbrains.annotations/11.1.0/jetbrains.annotations.11.1.0.nupkg
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.bcl.async/1.0.168/microsoft.bcl.async.1.0.168.nupkg
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.http/2.2.29/microsoft.net.http.2.2.29.nupkg
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nlog/4.5.0/nlog.4.5.0.nupkg
Error downloading 'Microsoft.Bcl.1.1.10 : Microsoft.Bcl.Build [1.0.14, )' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.bcl/1.1.10/microsoft.bcl.1.1.10.nupkg'.
An error occurred while sending the request.
  The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
  Unable to read data from the transport connection: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение.
  Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.bcl/1.1.10/microsoft.bcl.1.1.10.nupkg
Error downloading 'HtmlAgilityPack.1.7.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/htmlagilitypack/1.7.0/htmlagilitypack.1.7.0.nupkg'.
An error occurred while sending the request.
  The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
  Unable to read data from the transport connection: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение.
  Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/htmlagilitypack/1.7.0/htmlagilitypack.1.7.0.nupkg
Error downloading 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168 : Microsoft.Bcl [1.1.8, )' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.bcl.async/1.0.168/microsoft.bcl.async.1.0.168.nupkg'.
An error occurred while sending the request.
  The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
  Unable to read data from the transport connection: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение.
  Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.bcl.async/1.0.168/microsoft.bcl.async.1.0.168.nupkg
Error downloading 'NLog.4.5.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nlog/4.5.0/nlog.4.5.0.nupkg'.
An error occurred while sending the request.
  The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
  Unable to read data from the transport connection: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение.
  Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nlog/4.5.0/nlog.4.5.0.nupkg
Error downloading 'JetBrains.Annotations.11.1.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/jetbrains.annotations/11.1.0/jetbrains.annotations.11.1.0.nupkg'.
An error occurred while sending the request.
  The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
  Unable to read data from the transport connection: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение.
  Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/jetbrains.annotations/11.1.0/jetbrains.annotations.11.1.0.nupkg
Error downloading 'Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29 : Microsoft.Bcl [1.1.10, ), Microsoft.Bcl.Build [1.0.14, )' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.http/2.2.29/microsoft.net.http.2.2.29.nupkg'.
An error occurred while sending the request.
  The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
  Unable to read data from the transport connection: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение.
  Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.http/2.2.29/microsoft.net.http.2.2.29.nupkg
Error downloading 'Microsoft.Bcl.1.1.10 : Microsoft.Bcl.Build [1.0.14, )' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.bcl/1.1.10/microsoft.bcl.1.1.10.nupkg'.
An error occurred while sending the request.
  The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
  Unable to read data from the transport connection: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение.
  Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.bcl/1.1.10/microsoft.bcl.1.1.10.nupkg
Error downloading 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168 : Microsoft.Bcl [1.1.8, )' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.bcl.async/1.0.168/microsoft.bcl.async.1.0.168.nupkg'.
An error occurred while sending the request.
  The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
  Unable to read data from the transport connection: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение.
  Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.bcl.async/1.0.168/microsoft.bcl.async.1.0.168.nupkg
Error downloading 'HtmlAgilityPack.1.7.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/htmlagilitypack/1.7.0/htmlagilitypack.1.7.0.nupkg'.
An error occurred while sending the request.
  The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
  Unable to read data from the transport connection: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение.
  Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/htmlagilitypack/1.7.0/htmlagilitypack.1.7.0.nupkg
Error downloading 'NLog.4.5.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nlog/4.5.0/nlog.4.5.0.nupkg'.
An error occurred while sending the request.
  The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
  Unable to read data from the transport connection: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение.
  Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nlog/4.5.0/nlog.4.5.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/jetbrains.annotations/11.1.0/jetbrains.annotations.11.1.0.nupkg 1178ms
Installing JetBrains.Annotations 11.1.0.
Error downloading 'Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29 : Microsoft.Bcl [1.1.10, ), Microsoft.Bcl.Build [1.0.14, )' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.http/2.2.29/microsoft.net.http.2.2.29.nupkg'.
An error occurred while sending the request.
  The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
  Unable to read data from the transport connection: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение.
  Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.http/2.2.29/microsoft.net.http.2.2.29.nupkg
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'HtmlAgilityPack.1.7.0' does not exist in project 'VkNet'
Package 'HtmlAgilityPack.1.7.0' does not exist in folder 'D:\Документы\Dynamic cover VkNet\VkNet\packages'
Executing nuget actions took 3,45 sec
Error downloading 'HtmlAgilityPack.1.7.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/htmlagilitypack/1.7.0/htmlagilitypack.1.7.0.nupkg'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
  Unable to read data from the transport connection: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение.
  Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
Time Elapsed: 00:00:10.5541919
========== Finished ==========
```

Пользуюсь 17 студией
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Я уже не знаю что делать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта проблема по-моему мнению также связана с [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/806735/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-visual-studio-2017/810713#810713). Решение написано в том посте.